# ImageView bitmap offset correction

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing

I am trying to create an implementation of face-swap, across multiple images. These images are not taken from camera. They are `.jpg` files on the device.

I need to extract a part of an image of a face, using Google's Face Detection API. For this purpose, I extended ImageView:

```
public class FaceExtractorImageView extends ImageView {

    Bitmap image;
    Bitmap origImage;

    Context context;
    FaceDetector detector;
    SparseArray<Face> faces;
    List<Rect> faceRects;
    boolean changed = false;

    Face selectedFace;

    public FaceExtractorImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;

        detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
                .setProminentFaceOnly(false)
                .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS)
                .build();
        faceRects = new ArrayList<>();

        //The other constructors do the exact same thing.
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(final Bitmap img){
        image = img;
        selectedFace = null;
        if(!changed)
            origImage = img;

        changed =true;

        super.setImageBitmap(img);
        faces = detector.detect(new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(image).build());

        faceRects.clear();
        for(int i=0;i<faces.size();i++)
            faceRects.add(getFaceRect(i));

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                selectedFace = null;
                switch(event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        for(int i=0;i<faceRects.size();i++)
                            if(faceRects.get(i) {
                                .contains((int)event.getX(), 
                                (int)event.getY())) {
                               selectedFace = faces.valueAt(i);
                            }
                        invalidate();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(selectedFace!=null){
            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            p.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawRect(getFaceRect(selectedFace), p);
        }
    }

    public Face getSelectedFace(){
        return selectedFace;
    }

    public Bitmap getSelectedFaceBitmap() {
        if(selectedFace==null)
            return null;

        int index = faces.indexOfValue(selectedFace);
        return getFaceBitmapWithIndex(index);
    }

    //Returns Bitmap of face with index @index form the currently set image
    public Bitmap getFaceBitmapWithIndex(int index) {
        return getFaceBitmapWithIndex(image, index);
    }


    //Returns Bitmap of face with index @index form image @src
    public Bitmap getFaceBitmapWithIndex(Bitmap src, int index) {
        Rect r = getFaceRect(index);
        Bitmap created = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, r.left, r.top, r.width(), r.height());
        ImageView v = new ImageView(context);
        v.setImageBitmap(created);
        //new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setView(v).create().show();
        return created;
    }


    public Rect getFaceRect(Face face){
        Rect r= new Rect();

        //The constant values used below are for cropping the original image.
        r.left = (int) face.getPosition().x + (int) face.getWidth() / 20;

        r.top = (int) face.getPosition().y + (int) face.getHeight() / 4;

        r.right = r.left + (int) (face.getWidth() * 5.75 / 10);

        r.bottom = r.top + (int) (face.getHeight() * 3 / 5);
        return r;
    }

    //Get rect for face at index @index of image @img
    public Rect getFaceRect(int index){
        Face face = faces.valueAt(index);
        if(face==null) {
            Log.e("Face not found", "The image in the view does not have a face with index "+index);
            return null;
        }

        return getFaceRect(face);
    }
}
```

The above code does the following:

1. When the View is touched , it detects if the touch was on a face in the 
   image. If it was, a cropped box is drawn on the face using 
   `invalidate()`.
2. The `Rect` given by the vision API is cropped using the method 
   `getFaceRect()`.
3. The bitmap of the face is given by the method 
   `getFaceBitmapWithIndex()`, where the index is required if there are 
   multiple faces in the image. Otherwise, index is 0.

The problem:
The `Rect` I use when getting the bitmap of the face is the one given by `getFaceRect()`. However, I am not able to get the correct area. There is always some offset.

The images explain the situation:

`Rect` given by the Vision API:

[image]

`Rect` generated by `getFaceRect()`. This is also drawn in `onDraw()` when `invalidate()` is called.

[image]

The region that I get when `getFaceBitmapWithIndex()` is called:

[image]

There is something very simple that I'm missing here, but I'm not able to figure what that is. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug. Turns out, I didn't take care of the varying dimensions of different images, with respect to the View itself.

So, I put the code after the call to `super` in `setImageBitmap` inside the `getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener` and built a new `DrawingCache` there:

```
@Override
public void setImageBitmap(final Bitmap img){
    if(!changed)
        origImage = img;

    changed =true;

    super.setImageBitmap(img);
    getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            buildDrawingCache();
            image = getDrawingCache();
            selectedFace = null;
            faces = detector.detect(new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(image).build());

            faceRects.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
                faceRects.add(getFaceRect(i));

            setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    selectedFace = null;
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            for (int i = 0; i < faceRects.size(); i++)
                                if (faceRects.get(i).contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {
                                    //Toast.makeText(context, "Touched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    selectedFace = faces.valueAt(i);
                                }
                            invalidate();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```